# How to execute 2 Observables in parallel, ignoring their results and execute next Observable

Tags: java, rx-java

I have to execute 2 observable in parallel (don't care about their output), and when they both finished -> run another observable.

This is my solution, but I feel there are better ones:

```
rx.Observable<GameObject> obs1 = ...;
rx.Observable<GameObject> obs2 = ...;

rx.Observable.merge(obs1,obs2).takeLast(1)
.flatMap(mergeObj -> {

    return payoutStrategy.calculatePayout(gameTemplate, gameData);
}).subscribe(results -> { 
...
});
```

I use merge just in order to invoke the 2 obs's and then 'takeLast(1)' to ignore entering 'flatMap' twice.

This solution is far from being elegant but it works..

Any ideas how to make it better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concat` is useful for doing something on completion of something else. Because the type of `Observable` returned by `calculatePayout` is presumably different you cast the empty stream to its result type:

```
obs1.mergeWith(obs2)
    .ignoreElements()
    .castAs(Payout.class)
    .concatWith(payoutStrategy.calculatePayout(gameTemplate, gameData))
    .subscribe( ...)
```

By the way if `obs1` and `obs2` are not async sources already then you can do this to ensure `obs1` and `obs2` are run in parallel:

```
obs1.subscribeOn(scheduler).mergeWith(obs2.subscribeOn(scheduler))
    ...
```

Depending on what `obs2` is doing `scheduler` might be `Schedulers.computation()` or `Schedulers.io()`.

For multiple source observables you can also do this:

```
Observable.just(obs1, obs2, .. , obsN)
    .flatMap(o -> o.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .ignoreElements()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this approach.

Comment: Supposed I have 4 obs object which I would like to emit in parallel, that means I need to do: obs1.mergeWith(obs2).mergeWith(obs3).mergeWith(Obs4).ignoreElements().....
?

Comment: I tested it with a stub and it what I could see it that eventually it enters .subscribe() twice! which is not good!

Comment: oops I forgot to subscribeOn with obs1 as well, made correction