# Using takeWhileWithIndex to iterate over array of index and then emit an observable

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a list of number that every number represents an index.
I would like to go through the list one by one and for every number emit an observable.

How can I do that?

I have this snippet, but I having troubles understanding how to continue...

```
List<Short> seats = Arrays.asList(new Short[]{0,2,3,1});
rx.Observable.from(seats).takeWhileWithIndex((seatIdx, idx) -> {
    // Here I would like to emit an Observable
    updateGame(seatIdx, idx == 0 ? true : false)
    .subscribe(results -> {
        System.out.println(results);
    });
    return !seats.isEmpty();
}).subscribe();
```

There must be a better way to do this...

If you have any idea...
Thanks!

**EDIT**

I would like to go one step further and after omitting the loop of 4 iterations (which I don't care about its results), I would like to continue with the chain and concatenate more Observables.

```
List<Short> seats = Arrays.asList(new Short[]{0,2,3,1});
rx.Observable.range(0, seats.size())
     .zipWith(seats, (idx, seatIdx) -> { 
        return updateGame(seatIdx, idx == 0 ? true : false);
     })
     .takeLast(1)
     .flatMap(x -> x)
     .concatWith(calculatePayout(...))
     .concatWith(persistGame(...))
     .subscribe(results -> {
        System.out.println(results);
     }, e -> {

     }, () -> {
       System.out.println("COMPLETED");
     });
```

Notice, I use 'takeLast(1)' in order to avoid calling 'calculatePay' 4 times! - is there more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`zip` with `Iterable` gives you what you need:

```
List<Short> seats = Arrays.asList(new Short[]{0,2,3,1});
Observable.range(0, seats.size())
    .zipWith(seats,
            (idx, seatIdx) -> 
                updateGame(seatIdx, idx == 0 ? true : false))
    .flatMap(x -> x)
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: fixed the parameter to .range which is a count not an upper bound

Comment: Thank for helping me again :-)
Please take a look at the EDIT.

Comment: As per another of your questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616874/how-to-execute-2-observables-in-parallel-ignoring-their-results-and-execute-nex , use .ignoreElements().castAs().concatWith(). By the way calculatePayout would not be called 4 times...